# send selected checkbox values to another method

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Below code block is used to generate checkboxes

```
 $("#country").change(
    function() {

$('.container').empty();            
var item = $(this);
CtDataHandler.getCList(item.val(),{callback:function(data) {
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
$('#cContainer').append('<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox" id = "'+ data[i].name +'" value="'+ data[i].name + '" /> ' + data[i].name + '<br />');
}
}, errorHandler:function(){
},async:false
});
});
```

I have a separate block to get the values of checked values in its onchange method. Because I have to call a separate dwr with the selected values.

```
 $('.ckbox').click(function(){
 var  selectedValue=$("input.ckbox:checked").map( function(n){
 return this.value;
 }).get();
 alert(selectedValue.join(','));
 $('#selectedValue').append(selectedValue.join(','));
 });
```

Selectedvalue is empty !!!

JSP code

```
<td width="1%"></td>
<td width="50%" valign="top" id="catTd">
<div class="container" id="cContainer">
</div></td>
```

Any help to get the selected checkbox values here in this on change method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you assign value to "selectedValue"

It should be:

```
$('#cContainer').on("click",".ckbox",function(){
    var selectedValue= new Array();
    $("input.ckbox:checked").each(function (){
         selectedValue.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert(selectedValue.join(','));
    $('#selectedValue').append(selectedValue.join(','));
 });
```

when we use $.map function, this refers to the window object, not the current element.
One more thing with:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox"/>
```

I also don't see where the value is. For example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="ckbox" value="abc"/>
```

Comment: I added value like how Bipen has said. I want to get the values on clicking the checkboxes. So not sure where to put your code. !!

Comment: replace $('# selectedValue').append $.map( $("input.ckbox:checked"), function(n){
         return this.value;
}); with my code

Comment: or you can use the $("input.ckbox:checked").map as suggested by @Bipen. Both should solve the problem

Comment: $('.ckbox').click does not work with dynamically created elements. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Actually Bipen has been helping me from yesterday. Both the answers were useful. So got confused which to accept. !!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 //var selectedValue = new Array();
 $('#categoryContainer').on('click','.ckbox',function(){
   var  selectedValue=$("input.ckbox:checked").map(function(n){
          return this.value;
      }).get();
      alert(selectedValue.join(','));
      $('#selectedValue').append(selectedValue.join(','));

});
```

this wil append the selectedvalue comma seperated into `#selectedValue` element

**NOTE:**

your missed the value attribute of checkbox

```
 $('#categoryContainer').append('<input type="checkbox" class="ckbox" id = "'+ data[i].name +'" value="'+ data[i].name + '" /> ' + data[i].name + '<br />');
```

Comment: will i be able to print the selectedValue?

Comment: yes... did you try the above code ?? it should append the value.... anyways you can `alert(selectedValue.join(','))` before `$('#selectedValue').append(selectedValue.join(','))` and check

Comment: i tried the above code also the alert as you said. It dosen't print anything. also the on change works on deselect and not on select !!

Comment: did u add the value attribute in the checkbox ??

Comment: yeah i added the value attribute

Comment: change the  `change` to `click` that should solve the above problem dor select and deselect..updated my anser.. addedd click and get check it out

Comment: @sahana: when we use $.map function, this refers to the window object, not the current element. Did you try my answer above?

Comment: @khanh To I tried like this $('#categoryContainer').on('click ','.ckbox',function(){$("input.ckbox:checked").each(function (){
         selectedValue.push($(this).val());
         alert(selectedValue);
     }); }); I don't get anything. Am I wrong this way ?

Comment: well, should be alert(selectedValue.join(',')) to convert the Array to String.

Comment: @sahana here is an exmaple fiddle using map... http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/WFzAW/.. check it out...and my updated answer...

Comment: @bipen The function where I create checkbox is different and the function where I get values is different. Is this the reason why I am not getting the values? your fiddle is perfect. But tat doesn't work when I try in my code . !! :(

Comment: hmmmm... in that case it will be hard to tell you unless i see all the codes .... :(

Comment: @bipen I have edited my code based on your inputs. Can you please say If i m making any mistake ?

Comment: @bipen Thanks bipen... got what I need with the help of you and Khanh To !!! Thanks a lot

Comment: welcome... glad it helped... you can always accept as answer if any of the posts helped you...happy coding..

Comment: @bipen Actually Bipen you have been helping me from yesterday. Both the answers were useful. So got confused which to accept. !! Khanh To too contributed. :)

Comment: @KhanhTo  also corrected me.. so i guess he deserves it.. :).. anyways accepting answer of all your asked question is improtant (if it helped you though)... people here will help you more if your previous questions have accepted answer... and yes if your are confused then you can always upvote the other posts that helped you.. :):)..anyways happy coding..;)